# Javascript scope chaining inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, scope-chain

I am a student studying programming.

I have a question.

```
function a () {

}

a.prototype.prtSomething = function(arg) { console.log(arg); }

function b () {

}

var myObj = new b();
```

If I want to use the method of a in myObj, we use this code.

```
b.prototype = Object.create(a.prototype);
b.prototype.constructor = b;
```

That means changing the target of scope chaining. But why don't we use this code?

```
b.prototype.__proto__ = a.prototype;
```

I think there must be a reason to creating and using a new object. but I don't know. Please teach me. Thank you.

Comment: You're clearly studying well. Very few people would think to ask this question. :-)

Comment: http://tobyho.com/2010/11/22/javascript-constructors-and/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But why don't we use this code?

You could, and it would work, but:

1. *Changing* an object's prototype is generally not a good idea and *may* make JavaScript engines not optimize that object as well.
2. `__proto__` used to be non-standard (and still is outside of web browsers) and until ES2015 there was no standard way to change an object's prototype. ES2015 added `Object.setPrototypeOf` (and added `__proto__` to its web-only Annex B).

So rather than changing the prototype of `b.prototype`, typically we used to replace it instead.

(I say "used to" because I wouldn't write that code in modern JavaScript, I'd use `class` syntax if I wanted an inheritance hierarchy of constructor functions.)

---

**Side note:** Don't use `__proto__`. It's purely there for backward compatibility with old code, is not specified for JavaScript outside of browsers, and isn't present on objects that don't inherit from `Object.prototype`. (For instance, if you do `const x = Object.create(null);`, then `"__proto__" in x` is `false` and assigning to `x.__proto__` won't change its prototype.)

Instead, if you have a reason to change the prototype of an object, use `Object.setPrototypeOf`:

```js
function A() {
}

A.prototype.prtSomething = function(arg) {
    console.log(arg);
};

function B() {
}
Object.setPrototypeOf(B.prototype, A.prototype);

const myObj = new B();
myObj.prtSomething("x");
```

Also note that I've changed `a` to `A` and `b` to `B` to conform with standard JavaScript naming (constructor functions start with a capital letter).

Comment: Thank you for teaching me. I can understand. Thank you so much!!